# Add a row to SQL Server - receiving Invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I use the following code to add a row of data to SQL table. This code works fine when I try to add data to a table without a period in its name. In this case the tablename is "Table2.0". I do not have permissions to change the table name etc. I have used square brackets, but I still get

> invalid object name

at the `.Update` line. The idea is to update the values if field1 data ("1234") exists else add a new row. What am I missing here?

```
Public Sub ExportinfotoSQL
Dim cn As Object
Dim Rs As Object
Dim N As Long
Dim CheckStrQuery As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
        "Data Source=Server1;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=DB1;" & _
        "User ID=PowerUser;Password=1234"

CheckStrQuery = "dbo.[Table2.0] where Field1 = '1234'"
Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With Rs
    .Open CheckStrQuery, cn, 1, 3
    If Rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
     .Fields("Field2").Value = "Null"
     .Fields("Field3").Value = "Null"
     .Update
     .Close
    Else
     .AddNew
     .Fields("Field1").Value = "Null"
     .Fields("Field2").Value = "Null"
     .Fields("Field3").Value = "Null"
     .Update
     .Close
    End If
End With
  cn.Close
  Set Rs = Nothing
  Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `dbo.[Table2.0] where Field1 = '1234'` is not valid SQL - do you want something like `select Field1, Field2, Field3 from dbo.[Table2.0] where Field1 = '1234'`?

Comment: And why have you tagged Excel?

Comment: @DaleK The VBA code is probably in Excel. Granted it has nothing to do with his issue, but he's probably just covering his bases as he is not sure.

Comment: @DaleK I forgot to mention that Select * from dbo.[Table2.0] where Field1 = '1234' yields the same error. As I mentioned in my question, this exact query is currently in use to insert data into various tables. Only difference is this tablename had a period in it.  I tagged excel because I thought someone would know of any Excel in-built feature or add-in to insert data into SQL table similar to GetData.